# onload function revision to check value of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, field, onload

I am working on a website and I came across an interesting situation. In this particular website we are using a form that has given fields filled out that can be modified, etc. Part of this form gives the user the option between choosing one language or up to 6 languages. Each of these particular rows of the form are hidden unless the user clicks an add language button. There is also a remove language button. The problem that I am having is that there is an onload function that someone wrote to display the table on the my account page, but it only goes through and omits the sections of the table that are set to display:none; Here is the code for the current onload function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* call onload with table id(s) */
function TR_set_toggle()
{
/* toggleRow method */
var toggleRow = function()
{
    this.style.display = ((this.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '');
    return false;
}

for (var oTable, a = 0; a < arguments.length; ++a)
{
    oTable = document.getElementById(arguments[a]);
        var r = 0, row, rows = oTable.rows;
        while (row = rows.item(r++))
        row.toggle = toggleRow;
    }
}

onload = function()
{
TR_set_toggle('my_table');
}

</script>
```

It looks a little sloppy to me but maybe that's because I am new to javascript. Anyways, I want to change the function so it loads the table but also goes through each of the items that display none and check to see if they have input or not to display them. I don't understand the syntax of `this.style.display = ((this.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '');` **1. How can I add an if statement into this line of code? 2. How can I check to see if a field has input or is set to the default?** Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Vague, can we see the HTML too? What do you mean by "Default"? An empty field? Or a pre-loaded value? (and in the latter case where does this value come from?)

Comment: The `this.style.display` thing, anyway, toggles beetween `display:none` and `display:[empty string]`

Comment: This line:
       this.style.display = ((this.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '');
   can be written like this:
       if(this.style.display == '') {
            this.style.display = 'none';
       } else {
           this.style.display = '';
       }

Comment: Can you mock this effect up in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and tell us what you need it to do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I add an if statement into this line of code?

```
    ((this.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '');
```

is similar to

```
if( this.style.display == '' ) {
 this.style.display == 'none'
}
else {
 this.style.display = '';
}
```

> 1. How can I check to see if a field has input or is set to the default?

I dont understand your question. What do you mean with "field"?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand what that line of code meant. As far as field is concerned I am referring to a form field, like a text box, located within a table. The method given above supposedly takes a table and displays the table, most likely with the corresponding values of the items within the table. However the table is predefined to not display parts of the table and I want to go through those parts and check to see if the field has anything but the default. (in some cases it just says select in others nothing, etc.) I think I know where to check for it (within the `while` loop)